# editorfor not finding javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, onchange

I have got editorfor control to display jquery date calendar and I've onchange event defined on this. I checked the source code as well every thing seems correct. but when change occur on editorfor control it displays error : 
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'editorchange' is undefined

my editorfor control is defined as follow:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.holidayFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker form-control", @id = "holidayFrom", @onchange = "editorchange();" } })
```

and javascript function is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function editorchange() { alert("Changed");  }</script>
```

I've another textbox change function and ajax call with in same script tag. which are working fine.

I've also tried direct change method  $('#holidayFrom').change(function () {alert('change');});
this is not getting fired at all. I guess reason is because when jquery calendar changes the date in editor its not recognising change event there.

Can not use textboxfor  because that was giving issues with Jquery calendar.

I'll appreciate any suggestions what seems wrong here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this approach:

```
 $("#holidayFrom").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    alert(dateText);
  }
});
```

Comment: onselect not working either.  its not firing at change but not selecting the text it throw same error :
- JavaScript runtime error: 'editorchange' is undefined

Comment: Are you keeping the script tag in header or body?

Comment: it is in body and as I mentioned rest of javascript is working fine.

I've also tried with textboxfor and its same issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer please try that approach and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. that worked. but not sure why its changing dateformat to mm/dd/yyyy. I already have following code to set it to dd/mm/yyyy.

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 1 });
        });

Comment: As this function is running after the your document.ready function so might be its changing that inside. You can reset that inside this function also. Please mark it as answer as it helped you :).

Comment: I am not sure how to mark as answer.  I tried raising the number with up arrow but it says , its recorded but can not display publicly.

Comment: No there should be a checkbox on the left hand side of this post below the arrow for raising the number just tick that :)

Comment: Oops. didn't realise. Done. Thanks.